# Adding custom error page in IIS 7.0 in Windows 2008 Server

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6

For my Web Application deployed in IIS,  I need a default error page redirected to my custom error page.

I have included the custom error page in

Sites / Default Web Site / MyWebProject

Project Home -> IIS -> Error Pages -> MyCustomError.html

How should i map the default error page for any error ?

Comment: Check http://learn.iis.net

Comment: kindly allow the experts to share their comment.

Answer (score 0):

U can add the Error pages in the IIS Admin(Ref the Image Attached). Here U can select the Appropriate Error Code and add the Static page or any redirect URL to that page. make Sure the iis permissions in that folder.

[image]

Comment: where do you get that /index.php?error=404  - do i need to need to mention based on my homepage

Comment: keep the error page MyCustomError.html in your project source folder. And mention it as /MyCustomError.html.